# Binding the require function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, bind, require

I would like to include functions from a module into the current namespace. I was hoping I could utilize the bind function towards this goal, but I haven't got it working so far. Here's what I'm working with:

The module:

```
//exampleModule.js
this.fn = function(){return 7;}
```

The file which uses the module:

```
var example = require('./exampleModule.js')
console.log(example.fn())
```

What I'd like to do:

```
require.bind(this)('./exampleModule.js')
console.log(this.fn())
```

I was hoping that binding the 'this' from the non-module code would cause the module to load fn into that object, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I think you want the bind *after* the import, like `require('./exampleModule.js').bind(this)`

Comment: But the require function doesn't return a function - unless you have a bind defined in your module, its going to error out. (And won't be what you're looking for anyways)

Comment: what is your module actually exporting?  require returns a function if that is what is being exported....

Comment: This seems wrong `this.fn = function(){return 7;}`.  I would think it needs to be `module.exports.fn = function(){return 7;}`.  Then, you can execute your second code block properly with `var example = require('./exampleModule.js')
console.log(example.fn())` .  I have no idea what you're trying to do with `.bind()` as your actual goal with that is not explained at all in your question and there does not appear to be any reason for it in your question.

Comment: My guess here is that you're exporting your function wrong from your module and somehow leaped to the thought of needing to use `.bind()`.  So, now your question asks how to use `.bind()` with `require()` when that has nothing at all to do with your problem or the solution to your problem.  That's a guess.  See my previous comment.

Comment: This is also appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you describe issues with your attempted solution without describing the original problem and your solution is down the wrong path so it's very hard for us to help you with the actual and original problem. Please always describe the original problem in enough detail that if we known an even better way to solve it than what you've thought of, we have enough info to be able to offer that and in case your attempted solution is way off base, we can still help.

Comment: The value of this in a node module IS module.exports -  this.fn and module.exports.fn are equivalent. The goal with the bind was to bind the 'this' within the module to the 'this' in the non-module code, so that the definition of fn would be present in the 'this' of the non-module file. The problem is that the 'this' inside of my module is not the 'this' inside of the actual require function, and so the bind doesn't have the intended consequences. (It doesn't seem to change the behavior of require at all, at least from a cursory glance.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work, as I was confusing the 'this' within the context of my module with the 'this' within the context of the actual require function. Without knowing more about the internals of require, I don't know what binding would actually accomplish. This isn't the exact same thing, but omitting the var keyword allows modules to affect the global scope. (I'm sure this is obvious for those experienced with js..)

```
//exampleModule.js
fn = function(){return 7}
```

And the main file:

```
require ('./exampleModule')
console.log(fn())
```